# RecyclerView with various elements in the same line

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin, staggered-gridview

I would like to make a `RecyclerView` having differents elements per line depending on a boolean in the adapter.

In my app, you have some banknote and coins. I have to put all in a `RecyclerView`. First of all I want to show the banknote (2 per 2) and after the coins (4 per 4)
like this :

[image]

This is how I want the result look like :

[image]

This is my Adapter

```
    class MoneyAdapter(private val money_list: ArrayList<Money>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<MoneyAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MoneyAdapter.ViewHolder {
        val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_money, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(v)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MoneyAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        money_map.put(money_list[position].value, 0)
        holder.bindItems(money_list[position])
    }

    inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        fun bindItems(money: Money) {
            // if (money.isCoin) I would like to put it on a 4 element per line
            }
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return money_list.size
    }

}
```

This is where I declar emy RecyclerView :

```
recycler_money.layoutManager = StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL)
recycler_money.adapter = MoneyAdapter(getMoneyList(PrefsModel.currency)
```

I was searching a lot of examples but it's always with differents col/row using `StaggeredGridLayoutManager` and I want only change the number of elements by line (2 or 4) directly on the `Adapter`.

Comment: try using GridLayoutManager and use setSpanSizeLookup over it to define the number of columns to be displayed

Comment: try [this](https://mobikul.com/make-different-span-count-different-row-recycler-view/) as @Gautam said

Comment: thanks! I try to do this in Kotlin but it's not easy...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution thanks to @Gautam  :

```
val l = GridLayoutManager(context, 4)
l.spanSizeLookup = object : GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
    override fun getSpanSize(position: Int): Int {
        if (getMoneyList(PrefsModel.currency)[position].type == MONEY_PIECE)
            return 1
        else
            return 2
    }
}

recycler_money.layoutManager = l
```