# GridLayoutManager recalculate number of columns

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I need to do something like this:

[image]

How should I do this?

> Update

This is almost working.

```
    GridLayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 3);
    layoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup()
    {
        @Override
        public int getSpanSize(int position)
        {
            if (position == mElements.size()-1)
            {
                return 1;
            }
            else
            {
                SchedulePlanGlobal elem = mElements.get(position);
                SchedulePlanGlobal elemNext = mElements.get(position+1);

                if (elem.getRoomName().charAt(0) == elemNext.getRoomName().charAt(0))
                {
                    return 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    return calculateSpan(position);
                }
            }
        }

        private int calculateSpan(int position)
        {
            if (position == 0) return 3;
            else
            {
                int currentPosition = position - 1;
                int elements = 0;

                while (currentPosition != 0)
                {
                    if (mElements.get(currentPosition).getRoomName().charAt(0) == mElements.get(position).getRoomName().charAt(0))
                    {
                        elements ++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    currentPosition --;
                }

                int spanPosition = (elements % 3) + 1;

                switch (spanPosition)
                {
                    case 1: return 3;
                    case 2: return 2;
                    default: return 1;
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: can you share layouts?

Comment: @WaqarUlHaq Updated question with layouts.

Comment: Is it something useful for you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/49191165/1868841

Answer (score 0):

Implement and set `GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup`.

```
override fun getSpanSize(position: Int) = /* set value based on position */
```

With that you can define how many spans (columns) item should use. In your case 4th item should take all 3 columns and other should take only 1 column.

Comment: My number of columns is dynamic (tablet/smartphone), how to know how many columns my item has to fill? It's different if its in position 1, 2 or 3

Comment: You can set span size from resource (based on screen size) and you can do the same for span size lookup - read integer from resources for example. You can also calculate span count dynamically based on screen width.

Comment: I've updated question with more information, check it please.

Answer (score 0):

A different layout manager might be an easier solution.

I suggest using https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout

You would set the layout manager to `wrap`, so if your items did not fit on the horizontal line then it would wrap it to a new line, this make it easy to fit on different screen sizes.

Then for your 5th item that you know you want on a new line you would use the `layout_wrapBefore` attribute. I would checkout the `layout_wrapBefore` example in the docs